# How to deal with a Stationary DV and a Trend-Stationary IV in using OLS?

Tags: time-series, trend

I have a dependent variable that is stationary in levels. However, one of the IVs is only trend-stationary (stationary around a deterministic trend that I can extract from the series). In other words, I have a regression with variables that have different transformations. My question is, does this bias the significance of the results, including the significance of any other IVs (that are stationary in levels in the regression)? If not, it is probably reasonable to assume that it biases the estimated coefficient of the DP on the trend-stationary IV but not the significance of the effect since it shouldn't impact the standard errors (due to the trend being deterministic). Is that an accurate assessment?

Also, what if I detrend (i.e. extract a deterministic trend) from my stationary DV? Is this equivalent to over differencing and thus losing important information from the series? Does extracting a deterministic trend from a stationary series even make sense?

Comment: P.S. To clarify, the reason for my question in the second paragraph is that if I detrend the stationary DV, the significance of my other regressors disappears once I add the detrended IV. Thus, I'd appreciate an answer on this issue as it is essential for my model.

Comment: Hi: is this a VAR or a single equation ?

Comment: Hi, mlofton. It is a single equation model. It's not a VAR.

Comment: if the LHS is stationary and the RHS hand side has a variable that's trend stationary ( has a slope ), then you've got an I(0) on the LHS and an I(1) on the RHS so you can't estimate that model. But it sounds like the RHS is endogenous so maybe you need a VAR ? I have no experience with regressions where the independent variable that exhibit their own stochastic process ( except in VARS ) so hopefully someone else can say something.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The RHS variable isn't I(1) since it is trend-stationary. That is, it doesn't have a unit root. Nevertheless, it isn't stationary. However, as I mentioned, I have removed the deterministic trend from it thus making the variable stationary. There aren't any non-stationary variables included in the model. My original question is, does it make sense to "extract a deterministic trend" from the stationary (in levels) LHS variable (which effectively means demeaning it). I haven't seen anyone done that, so I am not sure if it makes sense or what the implications of this are.

Comment: Yeah, it's not I(1). I should have said that you can't have a not-stationary variable on the right and a stationary one on the left. But, if you're gonna de-trend, then you are going to have to somehow "de-trend" the other side in the sense that, whatever is done to one side has to be done to the other. I've actually never heard of single equation case where there is an endogenous variable on each side ? The only other place I know of which is different than what you are doing is the transfer response framework. I've never used it but the idea is to model the RHS as a time-series on its own.

Comment: then you do the same transformation on the other side and the algebra leads to a an arima model that can be fit on the transformed RHS. I wish I knew of a good reference but I don't. One book that contains a description is Box-Jenkins-Reinsel. I forget if it does a good job on transfer response. I was never a big fan of that book but, in different sections, it could be good.

Comment: The last sentence of the second to last comment should have said: "RHS as an arima model on its own". Also, you are kind of doing ( or trying to do )  transfer response by modelling it as a trend stationary process.  But, somehow you need to use the framework of transfer response to figure out how to re-write the whole model taking that model into account. That's currently above my pay grade !!!!!!! LOL.

Comment: Here's something about transfer response. I didn't look at it carefully but, if it's not useful, atleast it provides a lot of references that can possibly be helpful. If you find a good explanation of it somewhere, can you let me know. Thanks.  https://www.zora.uzh.ch/id/eprint/124682/1/20-3-808.pdf

Comment: Note that ( i'm sure you're aware of this but I'm saying it just in case. i don't want to send you down the wrong rabbit hole )  there's a whole digital signal processing area which involves transfer response and transfer functions but I'm not referring to that in above. The transfer response methodology I'm referring to is very specific to arima models in time domain.  But I imagine that a trend stationary model could still fall or be modified to fall under arima category since it's a time domain procedure.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say what you do to one side, you have to do to the other. I am simply making a trend-stationary variable, stationary prior to including it in a regression. The dependent variable and the other IVs are stationary. That is the same as simply differencing a unit root variable and putting it in the regression. Am i not allowed to do that? My understanding is that I should be able to as long as the variables are stationary and what changes is the interpretation.

Comment: I understand the coefficients would be different, but I only need this one transformed variable (which is now stationary after the deterministic trend has been removed) as a control. I also haven't seen anyone "detrending" an already stationary LHS variable to make it conform with a variable on the RHS in terms of transformation. After all, the other IVs are simply stationary in level without any transformation (just like the LHS variable). So, my question is, can I just leave things be as they are and keep the detrended RHS variable in the regression while the rest are stationary in level?

Comment: Hi: If you de-trend the variable and put it is in a predictor on the RHS, then that's fine as long as you aren't using your model for predictions. In other words, if you're just interested in the effect of the de-trended variable on the LHS, the model is valid but it's not valid for prediction.  I thought you were actually trying to build a model for the dependent variable so that you could predict it. But you are correct in that, if you are just looking at "effects", then I think it's okay. My apologies for confusing the issue.

Comment: But I do have one more question because, even if you are just interested in "effects" and not prediction, I'm still a little confused by the following: Suppose you de-trend the RHS variable, call it X, so that you have a stationary variable $X^{*}$. Now $X^{*}$ is still a time series indexed by time $t$ right. So, how to put that whole series into the RHS of the model. Is there a different regression equation for each time $t$ so that one element, say $X^{*}_t$ is put in each regression equation so you end up with a system of regression equation ?

Comment: I ask because I haven't heard of this approach before so I'm not 100 percent confident to say whether it's an okay approach or not. That's why I am asking my latest question. Also, I would still take a look at Box Jenkins-Reinsel's explanation of the transfer function approach. Both sides of the equation are modelled by using the ARIMA algebra to get all of the parameters on one side.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about the multiple regressions. All of my variables in the regression are time series and therefore indexed by t. The only issue is that one of them is trend-stationary while the rest are time series that are stationary in level. I am not sure if you assumed that the other variables aren't time series or I am misunderstanding you. Also, what did you mean that I can only claim effect, but not prediction. Did you mean that I can argue about the significance, but not about the accuracy of the coefficient estimates?

Comment: Hi: I asked about where you are going to "put" the series because, when you detrend it, you're going to have a vector of elements. So, if you are indexing by $t$, I assume you will put each element of the vector into an equation so you will end up with some large regression model ? Is that, correct ?

Comment: My intuition is that you can't use the resulting model for prediction because, by de-trending, you've modified the actual data.  If you don't think the trend has anything to do with the behavior of the LHS, then I guess it's okay for prediction but wouldn't that be not intuitive ? If the trend doesn't matter,  does one even know if the variable matters ? So, my issue with prediction is that you've de-trended a variable that seems to drive the LHS ? but you removed information.  I don't have a good feel for it but that doesn't sound correct to me ? Maybe someone else can say something helpful ?

Comment: I am still not sure I understand your first question. I am running a simple OLS and my detrended variable is detrended by estimating the linear trend using ols and removing it from the series resulting in a series that is stationary. That is the variable that enters the regression. I am not sure why I need to put each element in a vector.

Comment: Regarding your second point, I would agree if the variable was differenced since it changes the error structure of the variable and thus its impact in the regression model. However, if there is a deterministic trend, the error structure remains the same. Obviously you change the data associated with that variable, however, if the error structure of the series is the same, I think it shouldn't change the significance of other variables in the model and thus its validity (It will change the coefficient on the detrended variable which I don't care about since it is a control variable).

Comment: hi: In regard to your first comment, so, for this RHS variable, call  it $Y_t$ for name-sake, you run an OLS of $Y_t = a + b \times t$ in order to obtain estimates of $a$ and $b$.  Then, you calculate $Y_t - \hat{b} \times t - \hat{a}   = Y_t^{*}$ so that the de-trended variable at time $t$, namely $Y_t^{*}$,  has a constant mean of zero.   Is that correct ?

Comment: If that's right, then you use that variable on the RHS of your primary regression, so calling the actual response of that $Z_t$, you will have $Z_t = \beta_{0} + \beta_1 Y_t^{*} + + \beta_{2} X_{2} + \ldots \beta_{k} X_{k}$.

Comment: If that's right, then I understand what you're doing but I have to think about if prediction makes sense ? At a quick glance, it doesn't make sense to me but my brain is not really clicking at the moment. Atleast, if those things are correct, then I understand EXACTLY what you're doing  and apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I am doing. Well, the variance of the original variable $Y_t$ is constant, so I am only removing the trend component while preserving the variance. So, the standard errors shouldn't be affected, and what is affected is $\beta_1$, but that is a control variable for me and I don't particularly care about this response. I only need $Y_t^*$ as a control to estimate the impact of $X_1$, $X_2$ etc. I have seen people combining variables with all kinds of stationary transformations and I have read  that you can technically do that, but the interpretation changes.

Comment: To  my understanding, adding a detrended variable (with a deterministic trend extracted) to a regression where all other variables are stationary in level is least problematic since the variance is preserved. Mixing first difference or second difference etc. variables is I think more problematic since the error structure of those variables change. As long as the trend doesn't matter (and just the deviations from it) when it comes to the effect of this variable on the regression as a whole, I think I should be ok. Of course, $\beta_1$ will change, but the S.E. should be minimally impacted.

Comment: I will write in the answer section tonight when I get home just to have more space. ( it won't be necessarily an answer ). Now that I understand better what you're doing ( as far de-trending and then using the result ), I still have some issues with it but maybe those are not so serious ? The following question will help a little when I write a longer explanation, tonight. When you say "t" or "t+1", is t, one minute, one day, one week etc. Also, can you say what the thing is that you're actually de-trending and what the response is ? If not, that's okay.

Comment: yeah, the name dynamic linear models ( the statisticians name for the bayesian kalman filter ) has been around since the mid 70's. Statistics sort of inherited the KF ( which was from the early 60's ) but modified things a little as far as introducing the bayesian framework.

Comment: yes. I always forget the ampersand !!!!!!!

Comment: I would like to keep this general for anyone else reading this discussion. I think there should be a statistical explanation about this in the sense that it shouldn't matter what the variables are. Keep in mind that the IV in question contains a deterministic trend (i.e. it is a linear function of time). It isn't stochastic where things could ger more complicated. I think there should be a clear statistical explanation on whether one can use a detrended (trend stationary) variable on the RHS of a regression with all other variables stationary in level.

Comment: It shouldn't be a particularly difficult question to get the answer to, but surprisingly, I haven't been able to get a clear satisfying answer anywhere online. It's actually very surprising. I have seen a few people having the exact same issue as me, but nowhere did I read someone provide a clear explanation as to whether that is ok or not. It is ok, in terms of the fact that you are not violating any OLS assumptions, but there was no clear answer on whether it impacts the model in any significant manner (beyond not violating any statistical modeling properties).

Answer (score 0):

I have two issues but the first one may not be relevant.

1. When you de-trend your series, how can you one assume that the resulting process is not stochastic ? Once you take the trend off, the resulting series is not a constant, right ? So, it would seem to me like the de-rtrended series would have to be stochastic.  This is my first issue. I've heard of doing OLS where all of the IVs were fixed and I've heard of doing OLS where all of the IV's were stochastic. But I've never heard of using a combination. Theoretically speaking, some strange assumptions would have to be made about $X^{\prime} X$ in order for OLS to hold from a theoretical perspective when the IV's were of mixed type.  Halbert White's "asymptotic theory for econometricians" talks about the assumptions in OLS for both the fixed sampling case and the stochastic regressor case.
2. This is my main issue. When one uses OLS without time subscripts, the effects are viewed as "one-time" effects. By this I mean that, if one is trying to estimate a model of say weight versus height for say male teenagers, then the weight at time $t$ versus the weight of the same person at time $t+1$ is not an issue because the person is sampled once.

OTOH, when one builds an OLS models with time subscripts, even if the independent variables are not stochastic, the issue of multi-collinearity is present.

For example, let's suppose for simplicity ( this model is made up and will not work )  that the monthly stock price, $Y_t$
is linearly related to the steepness of the yield curve, so the 10 year minus the one year treasury. Now, if one wants to estimate a regression model using this data, it's essentially impossible for the steepness of the yield curve to not be correlated with the steepness of the yield curve at time $t+1$. But, when one estimates an OLS model, there is nothing in the model for handling this.
The effect of the steepness of the yield curve on stock price is not going to happen all in one period. It's going to be distributed over time. Maybe, when the yield curve  initially becomes steep, the effect is large, and then, over time, the effect gets less and less over time. But the less and less effect is still caused by the same steepness that occurred whatever time units ago.  In this case, ( which was constructed artificially of course ) the steepness of yield curve  effect is said to be  distributed over time. A standard regression model does handle this issue. This is mainly why I'm hesitant about your model. The assumptions in OLS don't work once one has data where the effects don't occur all at once. So, even if you want to not worry about the one IV being stochastic, I still believe that the time issue needs to be dealt with.

One methodology for handling time in a regression is through the use of a distributed lag. Formally, they are called "Autoregressive distributed lag models"  and they are mainly used in econometrics. A  very special one is the koyck distributed lag. If you want some literature references on this, let me know. Any decent time-series econometrics book should have a chapter on ARDLs.

At the bottom is one paper ( political science ) where time is deal with in an ARDL. The literature is enormous because it crosses fields so I'm not sure what to suggest as far as suggested references. My thinking would be some good time-series econometrics textbook. Baltagi does a reasonable job in one of his chapters.

I hope this helps some as far as what might be problematic. The de-trending could be okay but I bet the resulting series is significantly autocorrelated. If it is, then any results as far as estimated coefficients are going to be extremely biased.

https://www.lukekeele.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/AJPSR4.pdf

Comment: The paper I linked to is unfortunately a draft and is missing all the figures. I will try to find an unpaid version with the figures. If I can't, I strongly suggest paying for it. It's probably the clearest paper out there as far as explaining the basics of ARDLs.

Comment: Thanks for dedicating so much of your time in trying to help me with this issue. I have thought about ARDL, but they are usually used when you have variables of different orders of integration (i.e. a mix of I(0), I(1) etc.). A trend-stationary process isn't technically I(1). It is in between an I(0) and I(1).

Comment: It's on JSTOR. JPASS ( gives you access to JSTOR )  is a bargain if you download a lot of papers and you're  not in academics.   https://www.jstor.org/stable/25193805?typeAccessWorkflow=login

Comment: When you detrend a variable with a deterministic trend, you are essentially extracting all variation around that trend. In effect, you are shifting the upward sloping trend horizontally and are left with a completely stationary process since you extract the residuals that fluctuate around that deterministic trend. The actual series isn't a problem. You are right about the autocorrelation. That is why I am using newey-west standard errors. My issue still remains with the interpretation of such a series and whether it could be a problem conceptually. Once again, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: Yes, I understand your explanation that you are obtaining residuals. But then you are taking these residuals and using them as a column of $X$ in your regression. So, they must not be thought to be white-noise residuals, correct ? They have something in them that hopefully explains something about the movement in the response, right ?

Comment: Good to hear that you are familiar with ARDL's. I would think about whether you think that effect of each variable is carried over through time or is a "one-shot" impulse type of effect. If you think the former, then I think ARDL is the way to go. Also, you may try playing around just with your de-trended variable and the response and seeing what the plot of one versus the other looks like. Just as an experimental-get to know the data type of thing. Then, do the other IV's one by one.  I always think that dealing with multiple variables at once, although possible,  is really confusing.

Comment: As far as teh ARDL, once you de-trend the series, the ARDL doesn't know where the data came from so the fact that it was de-trended is not relevant. But, do you de-trend because the trend doesn't play a role in predicting the response and would actually make it worse ?

Comment: Don't worry about me taking time. If I didn't want to help and wasn't interested,  I never would have responded in the first place. I notice though that what happens is that it becomes one on one instead of a group thing ? Not sure why.